# Error "No module named 'azure.storage.cloudstorageaccount'" when using azure_rm_resourcegroup in Ansible playbook run by an Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible

As far as I am aware I installed all dependencies to use the azure modules in my Ansible playbook, but I am still getting this error.

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload_7l31ymh4/ansible_azure_rm_resourcegroup_payload.zip/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 250, in <module>
    from azure.storage.cloudstorageaccount import CloudStorageAccount
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage.cloudstorageaccount'
```

My Azure Devops pipeline:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Install Python'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID]$(az account show --query='id' -o tsv)"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID]${servicePrincipalId}"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]${servicePrincipalKey}"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID]${tenantId}"

- script: pip install ansible[azure]
  displayName: 'Install Ansible'

- script: ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection
  displayName: 'Install Ansible Azure Collection' 

- script: pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt
  displayName: 'Install Azure modules needed'

- script: pip install azure-storage-blob azure-storage-file-share azure-storage-file-datalake azure-storage-queue
  displayName: 'Install missing modules (to be sure to have the azure storage modules)'

- script: ansible-playbook -vvv -i inv site.yml
  displayName: 'Run Ansible Playbook'
  env:
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: $(ARM_CLIENT_ID)
    AZURE_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
    AZURE_TENANT: $(ARM_TENANT_ID)
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
```

My playbook:

```yaml
---

- name: config azure environment
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true
  collections:
    - azure.azcollection

  vars_files:
    - group_vars/common.yml

  roles:
    - roles/resourcegroup
```

and the role:

```yaml
---

- name: create a resource group
  azure_rm_resourcegroup:
    name: "{{ app.name }}-{{ dict.resource_group }}"
    location: "{{ azure.location }}"
    state: present
```

According to the documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_resourcegroup_module.html) everything should be fine. So, what am I missing??
I have been googling for several hours now, but I did not find a working solution yet :-(

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime. I have a working solution. I started from scratch, and created an Azure pipeline template without a role.

As an example I take my pipeline to create a docker container registry, but it works for everything you want to do in Azure using a playbook in a pipeline.
Just use this example to learn how I made it working. Hope it helps others who are struggling with the same problem.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'create vars file for docker registry playbook'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    workingDirectory: './playbooks'
    script: |
      touch vars.yml
      echo 'azure:' > vars.yml
      echo '  location: "${{ parameters.azure_location }}"' >> vars.yml
      echo '  resourcegroup: "${{ parameters.resourcegroup_name }}"' >> vars.yml
      echo '  containerregistry: "${{ parameters.containerregistry_name }}"' >> vars.yml
      cat vars.yml
- template: steps/run_ansible.yml
  parameters:
    playbook: playbooks/setup_dockerhub.yml
    varsfile: playbooks/vars.yml
```

The run_ansible step file:

```
parameters:
- name: playbook
  type: string
- name: varsfile
  type: string

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'install Azure CLI'
  inputs:
    #azureSubscription: '$(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)'
    connectedServiceNameARM: 'ARM Outstanding24'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID]$(az account show --query='id' -o tsv)"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID]${servicePrincipalId}"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]${servicePrincipalKey}"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID]${tenantId}"

- script: sudo apt install -y python3-pip
  displayName: 'install pip'

- script: sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
  displayName: 'ensure we have the latest version of pip3'

- script: pip3 install "ansible==2.9.17"
  displayName: 'install ansible 2.9'

- script: pip3 install ansible[azure]
  displayName: 'install ansible "azure modules"'

- script: 'ansible-playbook -v ${{ parameters.playbook }} --extra-vars @${{ parameters.varsfile }}'
  displayName: 'run azure playbook'
  env:
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: $(ARM_CLIENT_ID)
    AZURE_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
    AZURE_TENANT: $(ARM_TENANT_ID)
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
```

The playbook:

```
- name: setup docker registry in Azure
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
    - azure.azcollection

  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: ensure the resourcegroup exists
      azure_rm_resourcegroup:
        name: "{{ azure.resourcegroup }}"
        location: "{{ azure.location }}"
        state: present

    - name: ensure docker registry exists
      azure_rm_containerregistry:
        name: "{{ azure.containerregistry }}"
        location: "{{ azure.location }}"
        resource_group: "{{ azure.resourcegroup }}"
        sku: Basic
        state: present
```

Comment: For me, this was the magic: `ansible==2.9.17`.  Why is this version so important (or different or whatever)?